# How to create 2 row grid in CSS that contains 8 images

Tags: css

I am trying to create a two row grid with CSS, this grid should have or contain 8 images. What I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDyF4.jpge) have currently is a mess. Can someone please help out?

I need to make the images (4 images) 25% width... and they should span the entire width of the viewport.

```
HTML: 

<section class="container">

        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="resources/css/img/meals/food image 1.jpg" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="resources/css/img/meals/food image 2.jpg" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="resources/css/img/meals/food image 3.jpg" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="resources/css/img/meals/food image 4.jpg" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="resources/css/img/meals/food image 1.jpg" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="resources/css/img/meals/food image 2.jpg" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="resources/css/img/meals/food image 3.jpg" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="resources/css/img/meals/food image 4.jpg" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </div>
    
    </section>




CSS: 

.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.gallery {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
}

.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: See here, it's a good starting point: https://blog.logrocket.com/the-simpletons-guide-to-css-grid-1767565b3cf7

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the HTML and CSS using CSS Grid. Then your images will scale correctly with different viewport widths.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.container > img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="1. Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple options here, since you say grid and CSS, the first thing that comes to mind is the CSS Grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

You could also try using CSS3 `display: table;` and modify your HTML (scroll all the way to the bottom)
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#table-values

or you can simply use an HTML `<table>` element as well to get the same task done. All of these methods are valid!